# Debug Not Implemented for Crate Struct

Tags: rust

I'm using the texture-synthesis crate. I'm creating a structure `RenderSettings` that I'm going to feed into some of this crate's functions:

```
texture-synthesis = "0.8.0"
```

```rust
use texture_synthesis as ts;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct RenderSettings{
    seed: u64,
    tiling_mode: bool, 
    nearest_neighbors: u32,
    output_size: ts::Dims, //throws error
}
```

However this gives me the error:

```
`texture_synthesis::Dims` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`

`texture_synthesis::Dims` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
```

I see in the [source code](https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/texture-synthesis/blob/ce6a08430672a323c32b008081870b46e67eb5cc/lib/src/lib.rs) this definition of the Dims structure, which seems to implement Debug:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(test, derive(Debug, PartialEq))]
pub struct Dims {
    pub width: u32,
    pub height: u32,
}
```

I'm imagining my problem has something to do with `#[cfg_attr(test, derive(Debug, PartialEq))]`. I'm not really sure what this statement means, but it seems to suggest that I can use Debug somehow with this struct. So how can I fix this error?

Comment: `#[cfg_attr(test, derive(Debug, PartialEq))]` means that `Debug` and `PartialEq` will only be derived when it's in `test` mode (a.k.a you're running `cargo test`). I don't know why the crate authors decided to do this, but you could always make a newtype (tuple struct with one element) and make your own `Debug` on that since `width` and `height` are public fields.

Comment: @Aplet123 could you possible demonstrate what doing that would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#[cfg_attr(test, derive(Debug, PartialEq))]` is an example of [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) that will only derive `Debug` and `PartialEq` when the `test` attribute is specified (essentially when you're running `cargo test`.

If you want `Debug`, you could consider making a newtype wrapper:

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct DimsWrapper(ts::Dims);

impl fmt::Debug for DimsWrapper {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.debug_struct("DimsWrapper")
            .field("width", &self.0.width)
            .field("height", &self.0.height)
            .finish()
    }
}
```

Then, you could create one with:

```rust
DimsWrapper(ts::Dims {
    width: 5,
    height: 6
});
```

And extract the `ts::Dims` with:

```rust
dims_wrapper.0
```

or with pattern matching. If you want to be able to call `Dims`'s methods directly on it, consider implementing [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html):

```rust
impl std::ops::Deref for DimsWrapper {
    type Target = ts::Dims;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```